# Installation with composer fails

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

Trying to install M2 using Composer with the following:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition /var/www/m2
```

PHP:

```
PHP 7.4.12 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2020 17:04:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.12, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Composer:

```
Composer version 1.1.1 2016-05-17 12:25:44
```

This is the output:

```
Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.4.1)
Deprecation Notice: The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will take a higher precedence in phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/GitDownloader.php:238
Deprecation Notice: The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will take a higher precedence in phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/SvnDownloader.php:132
  - Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.4.1)
    Downloading: 100%

Created project in /var/www/m2
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2.0 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)


  [ErrorException]
  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

Comment: Just update composer to 1.10.17 , how to do that you can check on composer website

Comment: @BartZalas  this appeared to work. provide it as an answer so I can accept? did I miss a requirement note on the magento site? this seems like a pretty specific version requirement for composer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update composer to 1.10.17 this should fix the issue.

This and few different errors are caused because of that.
 
I use ubuntu, latest version of composer avalible was - 1.6.3 I think.

So I do:

```
sudo apt remove composer


php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

```
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"



sudo php composer-setup.php --version=1.10.17 --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
```

Check version:

```
composer --version
```

Remove all vendor and cache:

```
rm -rf vendor/*

composer clear-cache

composer update
```

Ref:

https://getcomposer.org/download/

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Error-during-Upgrade-from-2-3-3-to-2-3-5/m-p/463059#M3957